# ts-jest cannot run testing on imported ES6 modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I'm using a compiled ES6 library in my Typescript application. The testing fails with an error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'PropTypes' of undefined

The module it is complaining about is importing `react` as

```
import React from 'react';
```

If I change this to

```
import * as React from 'react';
```

then it will compile and run fine. Here is my `package.json`'s `jest` config:

```
"jest": {
    "transform": {
      ".(ts|tsx)": "<rootDir>/node_modules/ts-jest/preprocessor.js"
    },
    "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|\\.(test|spec))\\.(ts|tsx|js|jsx)$",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json"
    ],
    "verbose": true,
}
```

And here is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "jsx": "react",
        "allowJs": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noUnusedParameters": true
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*"
    ],
    "filesGlob": [
        "**/*.ts",
        "**/*.tsx"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "typings/main",
        "typings/main.d.ts",
        "typings/index.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

What configuration have I messed up here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `then it will compile and run fine.`

That is the way to go for TypeScript. `import * as React from "react"`.

Comment: It is going to break sooner or later. It should be avoided if at all possible. Webpack and SystemJS enable `import React from "react"` so anyone using either tool should prefer that syntax for importing a _non-namespace_ import https://github.com/nodejs/node-eps/.

Comment: @AluanHaddad isn't `import React from "react"` a *no go* when using `raw  TypeScript transpile -> run in node` right now?

Comment: @basarat, this is a module I am installing via `npm`. Typescript is suppose to be okay with importing JS modules. And in fact it is. The application compiles fine. It's the jest testing that fails.

Comment: @Kousha Exactly. Cause that code will not work with standard compile to node. Use `* as React` 

Comment: @basarat, again this is a module I am using via `npm install` and then using a React component within my .tsx file. The error is about the React component FROM module. Unless I go and open a PR against that module and force the author to use `* as React`, your solution is not helping.

Comment: @basarat yes it is. I would suggest `import React = require('react');` if you are using CommonJS and do not have another tool that creates a `default` for you.